# Wrap C primitive values in CFArray of CFNumbers

Tags: c, core-foundation

What is the best way to implement a method to wrap a C array of primitive numbers into a CFArray of CFNumbers?

I want to call something like:

```
double values[] = {1.2345, 678.9};
CFArrayRef arr = NumberWrappedValuesArray(&values, 2, kCFNumberDoubleType);
```

And tried this:

```
CFArrayRef NumberWrappedValuesArray(void * valueArrayPtr, CFIndex count, CFNumberType numberType) {
    CFMutableArrayRef array = CFArrayCreateMutable(NULL, count, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        CFNumberRef numberWrappedValue = CFNumberCreate(NULL, numberType, &valueArrayPtr[i]);
        CFArrayAppendValue(array, numberWrappedValue);
        CFRelease(numberWrappedValue);
    }

    CFRelease(array);
    return array;
}
```

1. It doesn't work (returned array has 0 elements), why and how do I fix it?
2. Is there a more elegant way, potentially avoiding the mutable CFArray?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`CFArrayCreate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/1388741-cfarraycreate?language=objc).

Example:

```
CFArrayRef NumberWrappedValuesArray(void *valueArrayPtr, size_t size, CFIndex count, CFNumberType numberType) {
    size_t i, n;
    CFArrayRef ret;
    CFNumberRef *ref = malloc(sizeof(CFNumberRef) * count);

    /* create array of boxed types. */
    for (i = 0, n = count; i < n; ++i)
        ref[i] = CFNumberCreate(NULL, numberType, ((char *)valueArrayPtr) + (size * i));

    /* create CFArray. */
    ret = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (const void **)ref, count, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);

    /* release boxed types and malloc'ed array. */
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        CFRelease(ref[i]);
    free(ref);

    /* return CFArray, without releasing first! Has to be done by the caller. */
    return ret;
}
```

Error handling omitted for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This gives me a compiler error on CFArrayCreate() that ref is not a (const void **). When I cast it, the correct CFNumber is created for the first primitive number in valueArrayPtr, but all following numbers don't make sense (e.g. 3.474077185876084e-310 instead of 2.0). Any idea?

Comment: @wolfrevo The compiler warning is expected. I've fixed it in the example. I've got no apparent idea why the values are scrambled, you could try using `NULL` as allocator, instead of the default. I've edited the example above.

Comment: Be sure to name this function with `Create` as the first word so it obeys the Create Rule. The scrambled numbers are likely because this accepts a `void *` rather than a `double *`. That means that the `[i]` is advancing one byte a time rather than one double at a time, so you're reading parts of adjacent numbers. You can make this generic, but you have to then multiply `i` by the size of `CFNumberType` (you'll have to make a `switch` for that; I don't think there's a `CFNumberTypeGetSize`).

Comment: Doh! @RobNapier is correct. `valueArrayPtr[i]` is undefined behavior. Why does that even compile? Any half-clever compiler should emit an error.